# Convert 5m OHLC data to 15m, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ohlc

I have a csv file with 5m ohlc data, it looks like this:

> T,O,H,L,C
>
> 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00, 13838.5, 13961, 13838, 13873
>
> 2018-01-01 00:05:00+00:00, 13873, 13920, 13800, 13800
>
> 2018-01-01 00:10:00+00:00, 13800, 13800.5, 13675, 13771.5
>
> 2018-01-01 00:15:00+00:00, 13771.5, 13795, 13711, 13769

I've found a script to download 1m and 5m data from Bitmex, but it seems like you can't directly download 15m candles, I've seen some similar questions where people tried to convert other timeframes but none of them worked for me.

I've tried `resample('15Min').ohlc()` but I get an error

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
> PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong while reading my csv file:

```
ohlcv5 = pd.read_csv('5m.csv', names=['T', 'O', 'H', 'L', 'C'], index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
```

Comment: try remove `names=['T', 'O', 'H', 'L', 'C'],` and then use solution from dupe.

Comment: @jezrael removed, this output looks a bit unhealthy now lol

             O               ...             C

open    high     low  ...    high     low   close

T

2020-07-01 04:30:00+00:00  9151.0  9152.0  9150.0  ...  9152.0  9150.0  9150.0

2020-07-01 04:45:00+00:00  9150.0  9154.5  9150.0  ...  9154.5  9154.0  9154.5

Comment: hmmm, if there is csv header is not possible use `name` paramater, because then get first row by original csv header. So it is reason why I suggest remove `names`

Comment: I don't find that answer helpful, what is 'dr5minute', I changed it to a variable name to which I assigned csv data, and assigned s = 3, cuz I need 5 to 15m tf, but it runs forever 
@jezrael